# crash when starting VTK example on python

Tags: python, vtk

There is this official VTK ContourWidget example on http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python/Widgets/ContourWidget

I’m trying to run this very example on Python 3.4 and VTK 7.0.0 and 7.1.1 without any changes and get python crashing completely and silently on the line

contourWidget.Initialize(pd, 1)

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you should use vtkIdList of indexes pairs in lines.InsertNextCell. 
This code works perfectly for me:

```
import vtk
import math

def mkVtkIdList(it):
    vil = vtk.vtkIdList()
    for i in it:
        vil.InsertNextId(int(i))
    return vil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    renderWindow = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer)

    interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    interactor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow)

    renderer.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)
    renderWindow.SetSize(600, 600)

    contourRep = vtk.vtkOrientedGlyphContourRepresentation()
    contourRep.GetLinesProperty().SetColor(1, 0, 0)  # set color to red

    contourWidget = vtk.vtkContourWidget()
    contourWidget.SetInteractor(interactor)
    contourWidget.SetRepresentation(contourRep)
    contourWidget.On()

    points = vtk.vtkPoints()
    lines = vtk.vtkCellArray()

    for i in range(0, 21):
        angle = 2.0 * math.pi * i / 20.0
        points.InsertPoint(i, (0.1 * math.cos(angle), 0.1 * math.sin(angle), 0.0))
        lines.InsertNextCell(mkVtkIdList([i, i+1]))

    pd = vtk.vtkPolyData()
    pd.SetPoints(points)
    pd.SetLines(lines)


    contourWidget.Initialize(pd, 1)
    contourWidget.Render()

    renderer.ResetCamera()
    renderWindow.Render()

    interactor.Initialize()
    interactor.Start()

    contourWidget.Off()
```